# Explanation of elvis' block system, specifically the block cache

Tags: elvis

From my browsing of the elvis editor source code, it appears that the block cache is a cache of recently accessed blocks, in the form of a linked list. However, I cannot figure out if this cache is stored in the session file, or in memory. Is this cache in the session file or memory? Could anyone better explain this mechanism?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This is a fascinating question, but I'm not sure how many Elvis users (let alone programmers) we have here, sadly. I hope you find an answer! If you haven't already, you might consider finding out if there are Elvis devs you could ask. Even Bram Moolenaar might know a thing or two about it from his work on Vim.

Comment: a cursory glance at the source code suggests to me that blocks are in general stored on disk but are kept in memory like a cache.  not an answer of course, but the true behavior is certainly going to be described by its source code.

Comment: @Mass I have gone source diving, but the source code has very little documentation and comments.  Definitely no nice `HACKING' file guide.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I originally asked this question on Stack Overflow, which is programming centric and would have lots of people who would be able to explain this, but sadly they told me to move it vi and vim, because that particular mod did not think it was appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @anonymoususer i’m glad it got asked here! I hope I didn’t sound like I was trying to push your question elsewhere; it certainly belongs here if anywhere. My concern is that you won’t get the expertise you need here to answer it, so I tried to point out some alternate avenues of research.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Of course!  I understand that.  I was just adding that to let Vi&Vim'ers know that this is not my first attempt.